# Login fail in management console with admin user after try to integrate user store in wso2-is and wso2-am

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I tried to change user store to MySQl and integrate that in Wso2-IS and Wso2-AM(api manager) base on this manual: [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+a+JDBC+User+Store).

After all steps in the mentioned manual, I tried login Wso2-AM Management Console with default admin user,but I got error below:

> "Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again"

while I login into WSO2-IS Management Console without any problem!
I added new user in WSO2-IS Management Console and login into WSO2-IS without any problem!

Also I have same problem on integration two Wso2-IS user store!

What my problem is?

**System Setup:**
wso2-AM 1.10.0
wso2-IS 5.1.0
Configs:

> wso2-AM user-mgt.xml

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>admin</UserName>
            <Password>admin</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/JDBC_demo_user_store</Property>
        <!--Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property-->
        <Property name="MultiTenantRealmConfigBuilder">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.SimpleRealmConfigBuilder</Property>
    </Configuration>

    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
          <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
          <Property name="driverName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Property>
          <Property name="url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.60.60:3306/JDBC_demo_user_store</Property>
          <Property name="userName">root</Property>
          <Property name="password">hamsa</Property>
          <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
          <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
          <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
          <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
          <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
          <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
          <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
          <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
          <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
          <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
          <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
          <Property name="SelectUserSQL">SELECT * FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetRoleListSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID, UM_SHARED_ROLE FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_SHARED_ROLE ='0' ORDER BY UM_ROLE_NAME</Property>
          <Property name="GetSharedRoleListSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID, UM_SHARED_ROLE FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_SHARED_ROLE ='1' ORDER BY UM_ROLE_NAME</Property>
          <Property name="UserFilterSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=? ORDER BY UM_USER_NAME</Property>
          <Property name="UserRoleSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME FROM UM_USER_ROLE, UM_ROLE, UM_USER WHERE UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_USER.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_ROLE.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID AND UM_USER_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UserSharedRoleSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID, UM_SHARED_ROLE FROM UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE INNER JOIN UM_USER ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID = UM_USER.UM_ID INNER JOIN UM_ROLE ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_ID WHERE UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME = ? AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_TENANT_ID = UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_TENANT_ID = ?</Property>
          <Property name="IsRoleExistingSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserListOfRoleSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER_ROLE, UM_ROLE, UM_USER WHERE UM_ROLE.UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_USER.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_ROLE.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID AND UM_USER_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserListOfSharedRoleSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE INNER JOIN UM_USER ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID = UM_USER.UM_ID INNER JOIN UM_ROLE ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_ID WHERE UM_ROLE.UM_ROLE_NAME= ? AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_TENANT_ID = UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID</Property>
          <Property name="IsUserExistingSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserPropertiesForProfileSQL">SELECT UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE, UM_USER WHERE UM_USER.UM_ID = UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserPropertyForProfileSQL">SELECT UM_ATTR_VALUE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE, UM_USER WHERE UM_USER.UM_ID = UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_ATTR_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserLisForPropertySQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER, UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID = UM_USER.UM_ID AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_ATTR_NAME =? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_ATTR_VALUE LIKE ? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetProfileNamesSQL">SELECT DISTINCT UM_PROFILE_ID FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserProfileNamesSQL">SELECT DISTINCT UM_PROFILE_ID FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserIDFromUserNameSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserNameFromTenantIDSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetTenantIDFromUserNameSQL">SELECT UM_TENANT_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserSQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER (UM_USER_NAME, UM_USER_PASSWORD, UM_SALT_VALUE, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE, UM_CHANGED_TIME, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserToRoleSQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleSQL">INSERT INTO UM_ROLE (UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES (?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddSharedRoleSQL">UPDATE UM_ROLE SET UM_SHARED_ROLE = ? WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID = ?</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleToUserSQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddSharedRoleToUserSQL">INSERT INTO UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_USER_TENANT_ID, UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="RemoveUserFromSharedRoleSQL">DELETE FROM UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE WHERE   UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_USER_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID = ?</Property>
          <Property name="RemoveUserFromRoleSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="RemoveRoleFromUserSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DeleteRoleSQL">DELETE FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="OnDeleteRoleRemoveUserRoleMappingSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DeleteUserSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="OnDeleteUserRemoveUserRoleMappingSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="OnDeleteUserRemoveUserAttributeSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UpdateUserPasswordSQL">UPDATE UM_USER SET UM_USER_PASSWORD= ?, UM_SALT_VALUE=?, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE=?, UM_CHANGED_TIME=? WHERE UM_USER_NAME= ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UpdateRoleNameSQL">UPDATE UM_ROLE set UM_ROLE_NAME=? WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserPropertySQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE, UM_PROFILE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?, ?, ?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="UpdateUserPropertySQL">UPDATE UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE SET UM_ATTR_VALUE=? WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_ATTR_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DeleteUserPropertySQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_ATTR_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenantsSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=?</Property>
          <Property name="IsDomainExistingSQL">SELECT UM_DOMAIN_ID FROM UM_DOMAIN WHERE UM_DOMAIN_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddDomainSQL">INSERT INTO UM_DOMAIN (UM_DOMAIN_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES (?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserToRoleSQL-mssql">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT (SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleToUserSQL-mssql">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT (SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), (?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserPropertySQL-mssql">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE, UM_PROFILE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT (SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), (?), (?), (?), (?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserToRoleSQL-openedge">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT UU.UM_ID, UR.UM_ID, ? FROM UM_USER UU, UM_ROLE UR WHERE UU.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UU.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UR.UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UR.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleToUserSQL-openedge">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT UR.UM_ID, UU.UM_ID, ? FROM UM_ROLE UR, UM_USER UU WHERE UR.UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UR.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UU.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UU.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserPropertySQL-openedge">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE, UM_PROFILE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT UM_ID, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DomainName">wso2.org</Property>
          <Property name="Description"/>
    </UserStoreManager> 

    <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
        <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
</Realm>
```

> wso2-AM master-datasources.xml

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

<providers>
    <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
</providers>

<datasources>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        ...
    </datasource>
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
        ...
    </datasource>

     <!--datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
        ...
    </datasource-->

    <datasource>
        <name>JAGH2</name>
        <description>The datasource used for by the Jaggery Storage Manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/test</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/ES_STORAGE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                <username>sa</username>
                <password></password>
                <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <!--datasource>
        <name>SAMPLE_DATA_SOURCE</name>
        ...
    </datasource-->

</datasources>
```

> wso2-IS user-mgt.xml

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>admin</UserName>
            <Password>admin</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
        <!--Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property-->
    <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/JDBC_demo_user_store</Property>
    </Configuration>

    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
          <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
          <Property name="driverName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Property>
          <Property name="url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.60.60:3306/JDBC_demo_user_store</Property>
          <Property name="userName">root</Property>
          <Property name="password">hamsa</Property>
          <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
          <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
          <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
          <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
          <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
          <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
          <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
          <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
          <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
          <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
          <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
          ... Same As Wso2-AM user-mgt.xml
    </UserStoreManager> 

    <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
        <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
</Realm>
```

> wso2-IS master-datasources.xml

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

<providers>
    <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
</providers>

<datasources>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                <username>wso2carbon</username>
                <password>wso2carbon</password>
                <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
<datasource>
        <name>JDBC_demo_user_store</name>
        <description>The datasource used for JDBC_demo_user_store</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/JDBC_demo_user_store</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.60.60:3306/JDBC_demo_user_store</url>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>hamsa</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
</datasource>
    <!-- For an explanation of the properties, see: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html -->
    <!--datasource>
        <name>JDBC_demo_user_store</name>
        ...
    </datasource-->

</datasources>
```

Comment: You don't have to define JDBC properties like "driverName" in the user-mgt.xml

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are able to login to WSO2 IS, create users and then log into WSO2 IS with those users too. But you cannot login to WSO2 AM with those users or the default admin user.

Your IS configs are correct. But, when going through the AM configs, I realized that you have not defined the jdbc/JDBC_demo_user_store datasource in the datasource xml. Since you refer it from the user-mgt.xml of WSO2 AM, it should be defined in datasources.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The following dtatasource JNDI name referred in your wso2 AM user-mgt.xml was not defined in your master-datasoure.xml:

```
<Property name="dataSource">jdbc/JDBC_demo_user_store</Property>
```

You may first do the same for this datasource as in your IS configuration:

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
            <username>wso2carbon</username>
            <password>wso2carbon</password>
            <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wish to do is configure your WSo2 IS and AM with mySQL as the the primary user-store yes?

Comment: I want to enable role based access control for wso2 api manager using xacml, based on [link](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2016/02/tutorial-how-to-enable-role-based-access-control-for-wso2-api-manager-using-xacml/). I  changed my primary user store to mysql on IS and I wnat to share it with AM. For that, I should link the API manager with the LDAP user store within WSO2 Identity Server.